# Using fgets() to read multiple lines. How to go to the Next line?

Tags: c

So I am opening a file that contains cards data for a card game I am designing for my assignment, basically each line contains 104 characters and each line is equal to a deck of card.

I'm using a `char ****` because of

1. number of decks
2. num of players (4)
3. num of cards (13)
4. card is represented like `9H`, `3D` means nine of hearts and three of diamonds, so it uses 2 characters.

I want to use `fgets()` to read multiple lines but I'm not sure if this works...

`for` loop is just the way how the deckfile is set, I just want to know if the `fgets` will go to the next line when it hits `\n`...

```
    di->cards = (char ****)malloc(sizeof(char***) * di->numDecks);
    for (i = 0; i < di->numDecks; i++) {
        di->cards[i] = (char ***)malloc(sizeof(char**) * 4);
        for (j = 0; j < 4, j++) {
            di->cards[i][j] = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char*) * 13);
            for (k = 0, k < 13, k++) {
                di->cards[i][j][k] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 3);
            }
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < di->numDecks, i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 13, j++) {
            for (k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
                while ((fgets(cards[i][k][j], 3, di->deckFile)) != NULL);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well, have you tried it, to see if it works?

Comment: This is insanely over-complicated. It really (and I do mean *really*) shouldn't need that many levels of pointer indirection to express such a simple problem. Also, [don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).

Comment: Wow, a four-star programmer!

Comment: looping mallocs always go well with looping `free()`'s

Comment: Never cast the `malloc` return value in the C language.

Answer (score 6):

`fgets()` is often called in a loop, such as this:

```
FILE *fp;
char buf[260];// or char *buf, then use malloc - make index size appropriate length for anticipated line len.
fp = fopen("C:\\somedir\\card.txt", "r");
while(fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), fp)) //where sizeof(buf) is the length of   
                                   //line you anticipate reading in.
{
    //do something with buf here;
    //The input of fgets will be NULL as soon 
    //as its input fp has been fully read, then exit the loop  
}
fclose(fp);
```

Your statement `while((fgets(cards[i][k][j], 3, di->deckFile)) != NULL);`
has a couple of issues, one is the `;` at the end.  It will just loop on this one line, and not give you a chance to do anything with the line that is read before it reads the next one.  Also, `3` is probably not the length of line you want to read, is it?  3 is the buffer size that will hold your card data, but the ***line*** you read from the file will be longer.

So, in addition to these points, consider the other ideas in the comments, and make changes as indicated.

***[EDIT]***   modified to read a file with "AS3D4C...(52 cards)" 4 lines
It will fill in enough spaces for 4 decks of cards.  You can use this to
see how to read in the data.  strtok (used before) works only when there
are delimiters, which if you can, I would recommend using instead  of
long strings.  Hope this helps.

*(Note, I used neither `malloc()` or `calloc()` in this example.*

```
#include <ansi_c.h>
#define FILENAME "C:\\dev\\play\\cards.txt"

int main()
{
    int i, j;    
    FILE *fp;
    char buf[260];// or char *buf, then use malloc - make index size appropriate length for anticipated line len.
    char *cardTok;
    char cards[208][3]; //4 players, 4 decks, each card is 3 bytes (eg. [A|S|\0], they all need a null termination)
    
    memset(cards, 0, 208*3);
    
    fp = fopen(FILENAME, "r");
    j = 0;
    while(fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), fp)) //where buf len is initialized at 260   
                                       //and well over the anticipated 104/line, including \n etc.
    {                          //note, fgets() will read up to n-1 characters and place a \0 at the end
                           //but will stop reading sooner if it sees end of line.
        for(i=0;i<52;i++) //i is card number
        {
            cards[i+j][0] = buf[2*i+0]; 
            cards[i+j][1] = buf[2*i+1];
            cards[i+j][2] = 0;
        }
        j+=52;
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

My text file looked like this:

```
9H3D4SQhKD1H9H3D4SQhKD1H9H3D4SQhKD1H9H3D4SQhKD1H9H3D4SQhKD1H9H3D4SQhKD3D4SQhKD1H9H3D4SQhKDKD1H9H3D4SQhKD
6C9H3D4SQhKD1H9H3D4SQhKD1H9H3D4SQhKD1H9H3D4SQhKD1H9H3D4SQhKD1H9H3D4SQhKD3D4SQhKD1H9H3D4SQhKDKD1H9H3D4SQh
2D9H3D4SQhKD1H9H3D4SQhKD1H9H3D4SQhKD1H9H3D4SQhKD1H9H3D4SQhKD1H9H3D4SQhKD3D4SQhKD1H9H3D4SQhKDKD1H9H3D4SQh
3S9H3D4SQhKD1H9H3D4SQhKD1H9H3D4SQhKD1H9H3D4SQhKD1H1H9H3D4SQhKD1H9H3D4SQhKD3D4SQhKD1H9H3D4SQhKDKD1H9H3D4S
```

Comment: basically the data on one line is just...
AH9D3C4S.....(104 char, well 52 cards and each card represent by a num+suit (A J Q K T 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 + Diamond Cloth Heart Spade) and every 2 char is for a player, so e.g. AH = Player1, 9D = Player2, 3C = Player3 4S = player4.

so im thinking what i should do to go make fgets go to second line...

Comment: Okay, just saw this.  See my edit then (in a few minutes).  Also my cards.txt does not really contain a complete set of cards, I made a few, then cut and pasted.

Comment: Dont't you want "//where 259 is the length of line with its \n you anticipate"?  A buffer of 260 will nicely read up to 258 characters, the \n and then need 1 more for the \0.

Comment: @chux - yes, thanks for pointing that out. did not update comments to match my edits before, just did.  Used a completely different approach last time, assuming file contained delimiters

Comment: @ryyker OK for here, but note: ran into past issues where code used things like `fgets(buf, 120, fp)`, but the `buf` size later changed to < 120 and `fgets()` did not get  updated.  Thus I promote `fgets(buf, sizeof buf, fp)`.

Comment: @chux - Thanks, Thats a keeper.  Will change it now.

Comment: @chux and if `buf` is dynamically allocated?

Comment: @ElchononEdelson - would depend on initializer for `malloc()`, would it not?.  eg. `char *buf;  buf = malloc(260);`, then `while(fgets(buf, 260, fp);`.  I believe @chux was just making sure I, and OP understood danger of changing variable lengths, without changing middle argument of `fputs()`, and offering way to mitigate.

Comment: @ryyker chux is promoting the use of `fgets(buf, sizeof buf, fp)`, because that way if some coder changes the size of the buffer, you don't have to change every call to `fgets()`. So, what happens if there's a dynamically allocated buffer?

Comment: @ElchononEdelson - That would have to be taken into account.  As I mentioned above, I believe coder would have to include initializers used in `[mc]alloc()` statements, each time `fgets()` is used.  I have had to do that when using `realloc()` in a loop when reading files of varying size or content into variables created using `char *variableSizeBuf;`.  I would also carry along an `unsigned int bufSize`, assign the value, and use for both `[cm]alloc()` and `fgets()`.

Comment: @ryyker  @ElchononEdelson E.g. `size_t Len;  buf = malloc(Len); fgets(buf, Len, stdin);`  In any case, the value used to setup mememory for `buf`, either via `buf[Len]` or `buf = malloc(Len)` is defined only once, like `Len = 120;` or `#define Len (120)` is then used in the declaration of `buf` and the `fgets(buf, Len, ...)` call.  Avoid putting the magic number in `fgets()`.

Answer (score 3):

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    char *fgets(char *s, int size, FILE *stream);
```

`fgets()` reads in at most one less than size characters from stream and stores them into the buffer pointed to by s.  Reading stops after an `EOF`  or  a  `newline`.

be careful with this : If a `newline` is read, it is stored into the buffer.  A terminating null byte ('\0') is stored after the last character in the buffer.

When you want to compare line , before you need to remove `\n` before null byte.

If you want to read single line.

```
char line[100]; // here you can use char *line=malloc(100);

fgets(line,sizeof line,file_stream);
printf("%s\n",line);
```

if you want to read multiple lines

```
char lines[20][100]; // here you can use char **lines=malloc(100);
i=0;
//if you use **lines allocate size for all lines with the loop or else you can allocate size inside loop and then read.
while((fgets(lines[i],SIZE_ALLOCATED_FOR_LINE,file_stream)!=NULL) && (i<20))
    {
    printf("%s\n",line[i++]);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) says,

```
char *fgets( char          *str, int count, FILE          *stream );
char *fgets( char *restrict str, int count, FILE *restrict stream );
```

> Reads **at most** `count - 1` characters from the given file stream and
>   stores them in `str`. The produced character string is always
>   NULL-terminated. Parsing stops if end-of-file occurs or a **newline
>   character** is found, in which case str will contain that newline
>   character.

Also,

The return value is `NULL` on failure.

If the failure has been caused by `EOF` condition, additionally sets the eof indicator (see feof()) on stdin. If the failure has been caused by some other error, sets the error indicator (see ferror()) on stdin.

<sub>Also check for [feof](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/feof) to ensure `NULL` was obtained due to EOF</sub>

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take the fgets input and input all of it into an array of arrays or string array how could you do that. I have tried different things but get seg faults